# Transmission daemon not working after trying to set up firewall to force it to use vpn

Tags: debian, vpn, iptables, transmission

I tried to force transmission to use a my vpn by following [these instrunctions](https://askubuntu.com/a/960752). Now it doesn't work at all.

I flushed the iptables rules and rebooted but it still doesn't work.

Here are my current rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 679K packets, 1123M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 719K packets, 1430M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

How can I get it working again?